# Username is not outputted - Firebase, Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have tried creating a screen which outputs a label of the users username. This is the code that I have written:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import SwiftUI

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    
          super.viewDidLoad()
          guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return  }
          guard (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) != nil else {return}
           Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value){ (snapshot) in
            guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else {return}
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))
            label.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY)
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            label.text = username
            self.view.addSubview(label)
       }
   }
}
```

However the text returns as nothing. Is there something that I am doing wrong or missing out? When I remove the firebase parts of the code and just add a random piece of text instead of 'username', then the label will appear with that text so I assume that there is something wrong with the firebase code.

Comment: There are many basic issues with this code: first of all this code uses UIKit, not SwiftUI. Secondly, all UI operations must run on main thread, so oyu have to wrap lines between `let label...` to the end of callback to main thread with `DispatchQueue.main.asynch { ... }` block. Finally, you need to debug if the problem is with the label, or whether the statement `guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else {return}` exits, in which case you need to see why nothing is returned, not why label is not set

Comment: No. 1. Find out what `viewDidLoad` is for.  No. 2. Run a search for asynchronous process.  No. 3. Use the main thread when working with UI stuff as Kiril S. suggests.